# how i can got the value who are define n times in the form in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i have a form where user fill the n time a information using add another textbox and fill them.

i put the name them as

```
textbox_1
textbox_2
```

now how i can got all form values who are start with textbox_1. any idea to do it in asp.net mvc

Comment: You could use approach Phil Haack described in [his blog](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get the value of this text box using javascript and save it in hidden field as comma separated then read the hidden field value from your action method(I am using jquery)

```
var AllTextBoxesInPage = $('input[type=text]');
var AllValues='';
AllTextBoxesInPage.each(function(index){
   if(index==0)
   {
    AllValues+=',';  
   }
   AllValues+=$(this).val();
});
$('#HiddenFieldID').val(AllValues);
```

in your controller class

```
public ActionResult MyAction(FormCollection MyForm)
{
   String AllValues =MyForm["HiddenFieldName"];
   String[] SeparatedValuse = AllValues.Split(",");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use BeginCollection from [steve sanderson](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) and optionally you can have a look at [master detail form](http://zahidadeel.blogspot.com/2011/05/master-detail-form-in-aspnet-mvc-3-ii.html)